# How to get, use and change values from a .kv file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So, I've been working on a very simple kivy app and am having trouble with the backend. How would you go about getting the values from text_input and changing label values? I've watched a few tutorials but their methods vary and I get error messages.
Here is my python code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App

kivy.require('1.9.1')


class MyWindowApp(App):
    pass


window = MyWindowApp()
window.run()
```

And here is the .kv file:

```
Screen:
    side: side
    FloatLayout:
    Label:
        text: "Side:"
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.7}
        text_size: self.size
    Label:
        text: "Volume:"
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.65}
        text_size: self.size
    Label:
        text: "Surface Area:"
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.6}
        text_size: self.size
    TextInput:
        size_hint: (.4, None)
        height: 26
        multiline: False
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.24, "y": 0.7}
        id: side
    Label:
        text: "0cm"
        id: volume
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.27, "y": 0.65}
        text_size: self.size
    Label:
        text: "0cm"
        id: surface_area
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.355, "y": 0.6}
        text_size: self.size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, place `Builder.load_file` or `Builder.load_string` in your `build` method.

To handle changes e.g. if the user hits enter in the side input use `on_text_validate: app.on_side_change(self)` or place a button to trigger the calculation and use `on_press` method.

The `on_side_change` method in your class `MyApp` will handle the change. It will be called once the user hits enter. See the example code below, for a basic calculation.

For getting/setting values from the labels/inputs you can use `ObjectProperty` or `StringProperty` from `kivy.properties`. In the below code I'm using `StringProperty`.
Important you need the `StringProperty` in your app class and use it in the kv file.

For the `mode` of your calculation I've added a property, so you can use it in your calculation method.
The `mode` is also used in the kv file so it's displaying the current mode.

The `switcher` dictionary is the Python way to do a switch/case statement.

## Example code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

kv = """
Screen:
    side: side
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        cols:2
        spacing:0

        GridLayout:
            rows: 5
            cols:1
            Button:
                text: "Cube"
                # on_press: app.mode = self.text
                on_press: app.setMode(self)
            Button:
                text: "Cuboid"
                on_press: app.setMode(self)
            Button:
                text: "Cylinder"
                on_press: app.setMode(self)
            Button:
                text: "Cone"
                on_press: app.setMode(self)
            Button:
                text: "Sphere"
                on_press: app.setMode(self)

        FloatLayout:
            Label:
                text: "The Volume and surface area of a {}:".format(app.mode)
                pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y":0.8}
                text_size: self.size
            Label:
                text:"Side:"
                pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y":0.7}
                text_size: self.size
            Label:
                text:"Volume:"                
                pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y":0.65}
                text_size: self.size
            Label:
                text:"Surface Area:"                
                pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y":0.6}
                text_size: self.size
            TextInput:
                size_hint: (.4, None)
                height: 26
                multiline: False
                pos_hint: {"x":0.24, "y":0.7}
                id: side
                text: app.sideText
                on_text_validate: app.on_side_change(self)
            Label:                
                text: app.volume
                pos_hint: {"x":0.27, "y":0.65}
                text_size: self.size
            Label:
                text: app.area
                pos_hint: {"x":0.355, "y":0.6}
                text_size: self.size
"""

class MyApp(App):
    sideText = StringProperty("")
    area = StringProperty("0 cm²")
    volume = StringProperty("0 cm³")
    mode = StringProperty("Cube")

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def setMode(self, btn):
        self.mode = btn.text

    def on_side_change(self, instance):
        print(instance.text)
        result = 0

        try:
            value = float(instance.text)
        except:
            # failed to convert 
            return

        def cubeCalc(val):
            return {
                "volume": val * val * val,
                "area": val * val
            }

        switcher = {
            "Cube": cubeCalc
        }
        method = switcher.get(self.mode, "Unknown mode")
        if method is not "Unknown mode":
            result = method(value) # result is a dictionary with volume & area
            #print(result)
            print(self.volume)
            self.volume = "{:.2f} cm³".format(result["volume"])
            self.area = "{:.2f} cm²".format(result["area"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

why you don't have a build method in your App class?
try this:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

kivy.require('1.9.1')


class MyWindowApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file("YOUR_KV_FILE.kv")
        return self.root


window = MyWindowApp()
window.run()
```

***Don't forget to change YOUR_KV_FILE.kv to your own kv filename***

since you are not using Builder.load_file method to load your kv file you your kv file name must be something like mywindow.kv but im recommended to use Builder.load_file because you can save the whole window in a variable and access it later easy and it also make you free to change your kv design filename